# OSX: How to set more than one file icon for my app?

Tags: macos, plist

I have an app which deals with two kind of file extensions, say `.abc` and `.xyz`. I want to display separate icons for these two separate extensions in Finder. How to do it?

Also, I want only `.abc` file type to get opened up on double click. For the `.xyz`file type, I just want to display its icon in the finder.

A sample Info.plist would really help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is relatively easy, though not exactly obvious. For the second one, it looks like it depends on whether you want to be able to drop `.xyz` files onto the app icon. If not, you'd change the `CFBundleTypeRole` to `None`, but if you do, it looks like you'd need to set `LSHandlerRank` to `None` instead (that still goes in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array).

Sample plist snippet for `.abc` files, with some placeholder values:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>abc</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>your-icon</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Your File Type Description</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>your.uti.abc</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Your File Type Description</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>your-icon</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>your.uti.abc</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>abc</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Naturally, to add `.xyz` to that, you'd just add another `<dict>` to both arrays.

Comment: What would happen if you declared .xyz in the `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` part but omitted it from the `CFBundleDocumentTypes`?  Would that give you the icon without handling double clicks or drops?

Comment: I'm not certain, sorry. My impression is that `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` is supposed to reference a type defined in `CFBundleDocumentTypes`, but I could be mistaken on that. Why not just try it?

Comment: Possibly also relevant - there's a `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` that works just like `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` but is meant for types your app doesn't "own" (for example, PNG images).